# 4.2.1 background_holo_dark xml

Tags: android

In Android 4.0 - 4.1.2, the drawable-nodpi directory in the framework-res.apk holds the background_holo_dark.png. In 4.2.1. the XML has a gradient rather than pointing to the directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="#ff000000" android:endColor="#ff272d33" android:angle="270.0" />
</shape>
```

What do I need to put in to remove the gradient and get the xml to point to a directory where I place the background_holo_dark.png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to use it as a background you can call it directly 
for example

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background_holo_dark" />
```

now if you want to use it for selection you can create a file in drawable and do something like that. let say this i called selected_item.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Active tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_gradient" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- Inactive tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_listpage_77px" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <!-- Pressed tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_gradient" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_listpage_77px" />

</selector>
```

and then instead of calling the background_holo_dark you do this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/selected_item" />
```